# How to disable the automatic variable inspection in PyCharm debugger

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I'm currently debugging an application and I'm observing a different behavior when running with and without the debugging mode enabled. In fact I'm troubleshooting objects that gets lazily evaluated (`Queryset`) and when running in debug mode, they are getting evaluated too early due to the automatic inspection of the variables that `PyCharm` does when it hits a breakpoint. This is usually handy but in this case its getting in my way to properly debug the problem...

I tried [this](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360000016220-How-to-disable-automatic-variable-evaluation-when-debugging-) but it didn't help

Is there any way to disable that behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PyCharm debugger has a [variable loading policy](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/variables-loading-policy.html) configuration option. Set it to *On demand* to disable automatic loading of variables.

I would be very surprised though if this would make any difference to the values of variables.

Comment: It did the trick, awesome! The reason why the values are different is that I'm troubleshooting issues with `Queryset` objects that normally gets lazily evaluated but pycharm inspect its values and so it was being evaluated at a different time while running in debug. Thanks!

Comment: @bagerard Fascinating. I had heard before about the [observer effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_effect_(physics)) in physics, but I didn't know yet that it can also occur in computer programs.